# How to control multiple Raspberry Pi from single server

Tags: pi-3b+, debian, rfid

Using raspberry pi 3B+ I am detecting RFID. I have done network booting of these raspberry pi in order to avoid the SD card corruption from Debian GNU desktop by following this [link](https://ian.bebbs.co.uk/posts/NetworkBootingManyRaspberryPis).

Now I want to control all these Raspberry Pi from a single server so that I can update multiple Raspberry Pi from my server. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what does `control` mean? ... what do you want to update?

Comment: Using Raspberry pi I am detecting the RFID Tag.  I want to have communication between one Server and multiple Client(raspberry pi)

Comment: The link you provided explains how to ssh into the clients, this would provide complete control over each of the client pi.  Are you asking about sending the RFID data from the client back to a central server?

Answer (score 1):

[Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) is a great lightweight tool for controlling multiple servers. You can control configuration, push software, manage updates, and much more. [Here is a guide that is Raspberry Pi specific](https://opensource.com/article/20/9/raspberry-pi-ansible).

Separately, [here](https://dev.to/cloudskills/using-containers-for-ansible-development-2n9n#Using-Ansible-inside-a-Container) is an article on how to run Ansible from a container to make the whole thing easily portable.